Shut down multiple linux systems (Raspberry pi) over network ssh
i have 6 Rpi 5 systems which i want to shut down from my windows pc.
I was hoping the put a range of IP addresses   (they are on my local network 50.100  > 50.106)
They all have ssh access too.
Is there  script i can run on my pc that will send a command to them all.

For obvious security reasons, you cannot issue a shutdown command to a Linux system unless you are logged in as superuser.

You would have to write the script yourself. The script would automatically ssh into each machine and run the shutdown command.
